# Using an MVC web api, can I find out the domain a cors request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cors, asp.net-web-api, hostname

So this is insecure and isn't my favorite option, but I just want to know how possible it is. Is there a way I could find the host in a cors request so that i could send back a Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "domain.com" where domain is any domain that uses the api. The reason being is I would like to be able to "use credentials" with what is essentially a wildcard.

I could have my end user send me their host name, but if possible i would rather just pick it up from the request itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its possible, assuming you are using the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors/) to enable CORS on your API, you need to define your own Cors Policy Provider:

```
public class MyApiCorsPolicy : Attribute, ICorsPolicyProvider
{
  private System.Web.Cors.CorsPolicy _policy;

  public MyApiCorsPolicy ()
  {
     // Create a CORS policy.
     _policy = new System.Web.Cors.CorsPolicy
     {
        AllowAnyMethod = true,
        AllowAnyHeader = true,
        SupportsCredentials = true
     };
  }

  public Task<System.Web.Cors.CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
     // Add the Request origin to the response.
     _policy.Origins.Add(request.GetCorsRequestContext().Origin);
     return Task.FromResult<System.Web.Cors.CorsPolicy>(_policy);
  }
}
```

Next, in your ASP.NET Web Api config code you need to pass this policy when enabling Cors:

```
config.EnableCors(new MyApiCorsPolicy());
```